# Error with multiple nested Any() in linq to SQL in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

The below EF query for me returns an error

```
var items = new List<UserOrderItem>
            {
                new UserOrderItem
                {
                    Price = 1.23m,
                    Quantity = 1, 
                    Comment = string.Empty, 
                    VenueItemOptionId = itemOne.VenueItemOptionId, 
                    UserId = DataHelper.DbUsers[TestConstants.TestUserAlternate].UserId
                },
                new UserOrderItem
                {
                    Price = 2.13m,
                    Quantity = 2, 
                    Comment = "testshort", 
                    VenueItemOptionId = itemTwo.VenueItemOptionId,                    
                    UserId = DataHelper.DbUsers[TestConstants.TestUserAlternateTwo].UserId
                },
                new UserOrderItem
                {
                    Price = 1.76m,
                    Quantity = 1, 
                    Comment = "testlongerandlongerandlonger", 
                    VenueItemOptionId = itemThree.VenueItemOptionId, 
                    UserId = DataHelper.DbUsers[TestConstants.TestUserAlternateThree].UserId
                },
            };
 vItems = work.Context.VenueItems
     .Where(i => items.Any(oi => i.VenueItemOptions.Any(o => o.Id == oi.VenueItemOptionId))).ToList()
     .Select(d => DataConverter.Convert(d)).ToList();
```

Error is

> Test method Web.Services.Test.PosServiceTests.AddTicketItems threw
>   exception: 
>       System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Model.UserOrders.UserOrderItem'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

Is it the double `Any()` causing this problem?

Sorry I should also post what the items list is, amended above

Comment: To isolate I just tried commenting out the select line, and it still throws the error so looks like it is in the EF line

Comment: What do you expect `DataConverter.Convert(d)` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
var ids=items.Select(e=>e.VenueItemOptionId); //To work with a primivite type
vItems = work.Context.VenueItems
 .Where(i => i.VenueItemOptions.Any(o =>ids.Contains(o.Id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your DataConverter.Convert() as it accepts primitive types and you're trying to pass the object **d**.

Answer (score 0):

Any returns true if the count of rows is greater than zero, otherwise it is false. Calculating Any given a value of either true or false does not make sense. Replace the second Any with Where and see if that works.